# Expression : To convert currency to standard number

Tags: javascript, math, calc

I am trying to format a currency to number.
For example :
element.getValue() results in  **7.461.259,60**

I use this expression to change the format to **7461259.60**
element.getValue().replace(/[^0-9-]/, '');

But this results in **7461.259,60**

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: What is the return type of element.getValue()? String, double? How do you reveal its value ("7.461.259,60")?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution :

```js
var str = '7.461.259,60';

var val = str.replace(/[^0-9,]/g , '').replace(/,/ , '.') * 1;

document.write(val);
```

Comment: `*1` for converting something to a number is a hack. You can just call `Number` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as above, but without regexp, which might seem confusing to some:

```
var inputVal = "7.461.259,60";

var noDots = inputVal.replace( ".", "" );
var commaToDot = noDots.replace( ",", "." );

var outputVal = parseFloat( commaToDot );
```